# Boost pre-processor error with BOOST 1.56 and GCC 4.7.3 (all ok with older versions of boost)

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, boost

I have a very strange situation whereby I have upgraded to BOOST to version 1_56_0 and code that was previously fine no longer compiles with gcc 4.7.3.

The code is a simple template used to determine if a type is a `boost::variant`:

```
#ifndef BOOST_PP_IS_ITERATING

#ifndef BOOST_PP_TEST__H__
#define BOOST_PP_TEST__H__

#include <boost/preprocessor/repetition.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/arithmetic/sub.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/punctuation/comma_if.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/iteration/iterate.hpp>

#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/config.hpp>

/// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
/// namespace
/// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
namespace utils {

/// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
/// @brief primary trait template that returns false for non-variant types
/// @param T the type to check
template <class T>
struct is_variant_type
{ BOOST_STATIC_CONSTANT( bool, value = false ); };

/// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
// generate specializations of the is variant template
#define BOOST_PP_ITERATION_LIMITS (2, BOOST_VARIANT_LIMIT_TYPES )
#define BOOST_PP_FILENAME_1 "utils_lib_is_variant.h"   // this file
#include BOOST_PP_ITERATE()

} // namespace

#endif // BOOST_PP_TEST__H__

#else // BOOST_PP_IS_ITERATING

/// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
/// Use boost pre-processor to generated template specializations for
/// boost::variants with 2 to BOOST_VARIANT_LIMIT_TYPES parameters 
/// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
#define n BOOST_PP_ITERATION()
// specialization pattern
template <BOOST_PP_ENUM_PARAMS(n, class T)>
struct is_variant_type< boost::variant< BOOST_PP_ENUM_PARAMS(n,T) > >
{ BOOST_STATIC_CONSTANT( bool, value = true ); };

#undef n
#endif // BOOST_PP_IS_ITERATING
```

This code is compile cleanly with:

- GCC 4.4.6-3 using BOOST version 1_56_0
- GCC 4.4.6-3 using BOOST version 1_53_0
- GCC 4.7.33 using BOOST version 1_53_0

But when compiled using GCC 4.7.3 and BOOST version 1_56_0 I get the following errors:

```
In file included from /opt/miniboost_1_56_0/boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/reverse1.hpp:1294:0,
             from     /opt/miniboost_1_56_0/boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/forward1.hpp:43,
             from utils_lib_is_variant.h:47,
             from is_variant.cpp:6:
./utils_lib_is_variant.h:62:67: error: wrong number of template arguments (0, should be 1 or more)
In file included from /opt/miniboost_1_56_0/boost/variant/variant.hpp:28:0,
             from /opt/miniboost_1_56_0/boost/variant.hpp:17,
             from utils_lib_is_variant.h:28,
             from is_variant.cpp:6:
/opt/miniboost_1_56_0/boost/variant/variant_fwd.hpp:291:53: error: provided for ‘template<class T0, class ... TN> class boost::variant’
In file included from /opt/miniboost_1_56_0/boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/reverse1.hpp:1294:0,
             from     /opt/miniboost_1_56_0/boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/forward1.hpp:43,
             from utils_lib_is_variant.h:47,
             from is_variant.cpp:6:
./utils_lib_is_variant.h:62:69: error: template argument 1 is invalid
```

I am unable to change compiler from GCC 4.7.3 for live code.
Is there a simple way around this? At the moment my choices are:

1. Revert to using BOOST 1_53_0
2. Abandon use of the Boost pre-processor and manually define the templates for `is_variant_type`

Comment: [This](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/variant-Warning-variadic-templates-in-boost-variant-td4656153.html) may help. Try defining `BOOST_VARIANT_DO_NOT_USE_VARIADIC_TEMPLATES`.

Comment: @cv_and_he Thanks that resolved it, can you post it as an answer, and I'll accept it. This code is used on 2 platforms - one compiled using c++11 and one compiled with c++03 - if it was c++11 specific I could have just used variadic templates here....